# Use insert, update, delete in one query using mysqli_multi_query?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Right now, I am using `mysqli_multi_query()`, And I have two operation:

- First-time insert
- Second-time update.

I've also tried both of them in one query using `mysqli_multi_query()`, But It is still not working.

And I'm working for more than 100's record so how many rows I can insert in one time.

Here's the Query :

```
$qry1 .= "INSERT INTO productinfo( productName, productPrice,productSaleprice,productImage,
       productLink, productColor, productSize, categoryId, ourceProductId,sourceId)"; 
$qry1 .= 'VALUES ("'.$productname.'","'.$productprice.'","'.$productsaleprice.'",
       "'.$productimage‌.'","'.$productlink.'","'.$color.'","'.$size.'",
       "'.$data2['categoryId'].'","'.$so‌urcePid.'","'.$sourceId.'");';
```

Comment: Please post the query.

Comment: Include your code everything is a guess without it. Per the manual `Executes one or multiple queries which are concatenated by a semicolon.`

Comment: did you RTFM? http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php - The "F" stands for "Fabulous" here ;-)

Comment: *"But It is not working."* - Define "not working".

Comment: `$qry1 .= "INSERT INTO `productinfo`( `productName`, `productPrice`, `productSaleprice`, `productImage`, `productLink`, `productColor`, `productSize`, `categoryId`, `sourceProductId`, `sourceId`)";
            $qry1 .= 'VALUES ("'.$productname.'","'.$productprice.'","'.$productsaleprice.'","'.$productimage.'","'.$productlink.'","'.$color.'","'.$size.'","'.$data2['categoryId'].'","'.$sourcePid.'","'.$sourceId.'");';
           `

Comment: please don't that ^ delete it and post it (full real/actual code) in your question. Nobody will ever read that and it's only 1 line.

Comment: Oh I give up. Good luck with that.

Comment: It is working but many time it is not.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with statement:

```
INSERT INTO <table_name> (<PK_name>, <field_name>,...) VALUES (<PK_value>, <field_value,...),(<field_value,...), (<field_value,...)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE field_name = VALUES(<field_name>)
```

You can insert more than 100 rows at once with this statement.

Comment: I think OP knows how to construct an insert statement. Questions is about the multi queries in PHP.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there is a limitation in your mysql server so that big queries will fail:

If you'll get an error like "Mysql Error (1153): Got a packet bigger than 'max_allowed_packet' bytes" you should check the "max_allowed_packet" option in you mysql configuration.

Please check the following comment in the doc of mysqli_multi_query:
http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php#97354

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use multi_query unless you precisely know what are you doing.

Otherwise, use conventional separate calls to query()/prepare()